# Creating A Green Matrix Activity Indicator : Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a `green matrix activity indicator` like this :-

[image]

Not exactly like this but something like this to show that i am processing something very important and backend coding is going on. Please provide possible suggest.

Comment: Share what exactly did you try so far and didn't work

Comment: i don't what to do in this case

Comment: @shubhammishra does below answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest following things:

1) Add this label in your view (https://github.com/buubui/TypeOutAnimationLabel)

2) Set black text background

3) Set text what you want, your text will be animating.

Comment: yes it could be possible solution, but now i am thing matrix video is better